# Do anyone know why I build boost on macOS but there's no boost::fiber lib created?

Tags: c++, macos, boost, build, boost-fiber

I am working on writing some code with boost::fiber as coroutine. The code works well on windows, but when I clone it (via git) to macOS, I found cmake couldn't find boost::fiber.

On both windows and macOS, I built and installed boost by myself like `./boostrap.sh --with-libraries=all` and `(sudo) ./b2 install -a`, besides that I also built on Ubuntu 20.04 for testing, on linux & windows, there's libfiber.a or .so generated in the installed folder. But on macOS, there's not.

my macbook air has been fully reinstalled for only one week. I think the macOS version and the clang version should be very very closed to the latest.

May I know if anyone has been there and figured out how to make the boost::fiber to be built on macOS?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the reason: The boost::fiber needs some new features of c++17.

With the following commands, I can make the boost::fiber to be built and installed on my mac(OS: 10.15.5, gcc: Apple clang version 11.0.3):

`./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=all`

`sudo ./b2 cxxflags=-std=c++17 install -a > out.txt 2>&1`

Just remark the commands here. May be somebody else will run into the same issue...